# numpy array indexing in multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array:

```
theta = np.random.normal(size = [1000, 30, 80, 10])
```

I have an index array:

```
delta = np.empty([1000, 30, 50], dtype = int)
delta[0,:] = np.arange(50) # stand-in for integer indexing
```

I want to index the `theta` array using the `delta` array.  That is, I want something like

```
theta[0,delta[0]]
```

Where the entry associated with `delta[0,20,11]` will be `theta[0,20,delta[0,20,11]]`.  E.g., I want to back out the row index.  How would I go about this?

Optimally, the output of this would be either have shape `[30,50,10]` or `[30*50, 10]`.

I'm now using:
I'm now using:

```
theta_unravel = np.repeat(np.arange(30), 50)
theta[0,theta_unravel,delta[0].ravel()]
```

which appears to work (delivers `[30 * 50, 10]` result), but I don't know if this is an ideal solution.  Rather, I don't know if this is the fastest solution.

Comment: Your `delta` doesn't make sense.  It has shape (3,).  Did you mean a (1000,30,50) shaped indexing array?  WIth valid values for the last dimension of `theta`?

Comment: EDIT:  Yeah, I realize what you mean now.  doh!.Right now, the values in `delta` are an integer index of the third axis of `theta`.  The second axis of `theta` should be inferred by the row on the second axis of `delta`. 

So, by relationships,  `delta.shape[0] == theta.shape[0]`, `delta.shape[1] == theta.shape[1]`, and `delta.max() < theta.shape[2]`.

Comment: As an aside, you might consider using `np.empty_like(theta)`, which creates an empty array with the same shape and data type as `theta`

Answer (score 1):

I think this illustrates what you are trying to - with a smaller 3d array:

```
In [758]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(3,4,2)
In [759]: y = np.ones((3,3),int)
In [760]: x[np.arange(3)[:,None],np.arange(3),y]
Out[760]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
       [ 9, 11, 13],
       [17, 19, 21]])
```

`y` is (3,3), to the indices for the other dimensions must broadcast to the same shape.

```
In [761]: x
Out[761]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
In [762]: x[np.arange(3)[:,None],np.arange(3),y]=0
In [763]: x
Out[763]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 2,  0],
        [ 4,  0],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  0],
        [10,  0],
        [12,  0],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16,  0],
        [18,  0],
        [20,  0],
        [22, 23]]])
```

Since I used `ones` to create `y` (too lazy to do something fancier), that's the same as:

```
In [765]: x[:,:,1]
Out[765]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 23]])
In [766]: x[:,:3,1]
Out[766]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

To be used this way `y` has to have values in range of the last dimension, here 2.